# 802.11ac - Where is the pre-approval equipment?

Tags: wireless-networking

I remember when 802.11n came out, there were products on the market for a long long time before it was an approved standard... Heck, Apple had it build in their laptops before is was an approved standard - if I'm not mistaken. I'm reading 802.11ac is the next standard in line... Where is all the pre-approval equipment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ac) on 802.11ac:

> As of April 2011, there are no consumer devices implementing the draft specification.

Now if you are asking *why* this is, there really is no way to know why any given company has not released anything yet.

Comment: Disappointing :-(

Answer (score 0):

[802.11n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009) is still a very new technology that has already [taken 7 years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009#Timeline) to get standardized. Since 802.11ac is still being developed, you shouldn't expect to see more of it for another few years.

Comment: It may have only been standardized recently, but 802.11n equipment was around long before that. Its not as "new" as the standardization date suggests.